# For security reasons, framing is not allowed

Tags: php, facebook, security

Trying to set up my first FB app, I tried using different PHP example codes, but for some reason when I try to access the app, I always get a Java window saying `For security reasons, framing is not allowed`. I have SSL on my server, and another FB app on my server that's not using `FB SDK` is working fine. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You will get that same error on StackOverflow if you  try to open it in a frame as well. This is due to security concerns as it is the first step towards clickjacking a site. See this Coding Horror [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html) for a full explanation.

TL;DR; Don't frame external sites...including FB which is in a different space than your server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I get the same message if I try to access the app directly (not through FB).